# How to deal with non-independent data when comparing populations across a range of distances

Tags: mixed-model, distance, independence

I am trying to figure out how to carry out an analysis but am having trouble finding any information. I am interested in finding out whether values of sensitivity across populations are more similar when they are closer together, and less similar when they are further apart (see figure below).

[image]

The problem is that the data are not independent. The values on the Y-axis are the difference between two population sensitivities. As a result, the difference in sensitivity between population 1 and 2 uses some of the same information as the difference between populations 1 and 3. This means that if you were to carry out a normal regression on the data the standard errors would be much smaller than they actually are, so you are more likely to get a “significant” result where you might not actually have one.

It would be great if anyone knew of a way to solve this issue of independence so that I can get a slope estimate with accurate standard errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Hubert-White sandwich estimators while clustering your data? This relaxes the assumption of independent errors within groups but retains the assumption for between groups. If you are a Stata user, these can be easily estimated with vce(cluster X), or simply cluster(X).